# Does parallel STL handle insert iterators such as std::back_insert_iterator?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, stl, c++17, stl-algorithm

Are parallel STL algorithms compliant with a `std::back_insert_iterator`??

I might be misinterpreting the difference between `std::par` and `std::par_vec`, does `std::par_vec` mean that the output range is required to be pre-allocated?

**Code example:**

```
auto numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
auto squared = std::vector<int>{};
std::transform(
  **std::par/std::par_vec,**
  numbers.begin(),
  numbers.end(),
  std::back_inserter(squared),
  [](auto val) { 
    return val*val; 
  }
);
```

*Update*

*Simplified questions as my first question was a result of misreading an article.*

Comment: Are you somehow reading a 4-month-old cached version of that page? Because that's not what it says.

Comment: Have you seen the source code for the Khronos  SYCL parallel algorithms implementation for C++17? I think you'll find the code on GitHub to be insightful towards answering this question and more. URL is https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SyclParallelSTL

Comment: @T.C. I misread the article, updated the question

Answer (score 4):

> Are parallel STL algorithms compliant with a std::back_insert_iterator??

[N4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) specifies (28.6.4) as follows.

The older, pre-execution-policy, overload of `std::transform`, uses input iterators and output iterators.

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryOperation>
OutputIterator transform(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
    OutputIterator result, UnaryOperation op);
```

the newer overload, using execution policies, uses forward iterators:

```
template<class ExecutionPolicy, class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2, class UnaryOperation>
ForwardIterator2 transform(ExecutionPolicy&& exec,
    ForwardIterator1 first, ForwardIterator1 last,
    ForwardIterator2 result, UnaryOperation op);
```

So it seems like you can't use `back_insert_iterator` with the new overload, as it doesn't meet the  [forward iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) concept requirements.

> does std::par_vec mean that the output range is required to be pre-allocated?

`std::par_vec` refers to vectorization in the sense of [vectorization vs. parallelization](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/611104). It specifies that both can be used.

Comment: I believe this answer is spot on. Took me a while to parse the phrasing though. I can better understand what you're saying when stated more like: While the pre-C++17 version of `transform` takes an `OutputIterator` which `back_insert_iterator` satisfies, the new `ExecutionPolicy` accepting version, as described by N4659, takes a `ForwardIterator`, which `back_insert_iterator` doesn't satisfy.

Comment: @LouisLangholtz Many thanks for your comment. I agree with it, and tried to change the phrasing accordingly. Please feel free to edit further, though.

Comment: So I suppose the answer is no, you cannot use a back_inserter?

Comment: @ViktorSehr In implementations that conform to N4659 - no, IMHO.

Comment: @AmiTavory Thanks, ftr I think it makes full sense.

Comment: @ViktorSehr No problem. All the best.